# Beefeater gin - unique bottle id

Tags: bottles, gin, identification

I found an old bottle of Gin my parents had.  They probably bought it late 60's or early 70's.  I had a look through images of Beefeater Gin bottles and I can't find the same bottle.  The photos don't show the correct proportion - the neck is about 1/3 of the length.

It also has a unique identifier on the bottle.  I don't know if its the bottle id or an id for the batch or the product.

Does anyone know what this id is?

[image: Back of gin bottle with some ID]

[image: Front of gin bottle]